# Dynamic range in Calc OO

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, calc

I am fairly new to OpenOffice Calc.I googled my problem for weeks. I haven"t found a reasonable solution to my problem.. So i decided to post it here.
Say: B1 = 4, I need to put some values into A1 to A4. If B1=2, I need values in A1 to A2. SO I would need a dynamic range, something like A1 to A1+value of B1.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way: create a defined name with a refersto of

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,0,$B$1,1)
```

Comment: thx for your answer. could you please elaborate a little bit more? as I said I am a beginner...unfortunately